# Label is always on top when using with startAdornment MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, label

I'm trying to use Input with startAdornment. But in this case label is always on top.
[image]
I want label will be on the same line with the icon when input is empty and move on top when the user tries to write smth. How can I do it?

```
<FormControl sx={{ m: 1, width: '25ch' }} variant="standard">
      <InputLabel htmlFor="standard-adornment-password">Password</InputLabel>
      <Input
        id="standard-adornment-password"
        type={values.showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
        value={values.password}
        onChange={handleChange('password')}
        startAdornment={
          <InputAdornment position="start">
            <IconButton
              aria-label="toggle password visibility"
              onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
              onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
            >
              {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
            </IconButton>
          </InputAdornment>
        }
      />
    </FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `TextField` instead of `InputLabel` and `Input` components and move the icon outside of the `TextField` and wrap them with a `flex` styled component like this:

```
<Box sx={{ m: 1, width: "25ch", display: "flex", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
  <IconButton
    aria-label="toggle password visibility"
    onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
  >
    {values.showPassword ? <VisibilityOff /> : <Visibility />}
  </IconButton>
  <TextField
    label="Password"
    id="standard-adornment-password"
    type={values.showPassword ? "text" : "password"}
    value={values.password}
    onChange={(e) => handleChange("password", e.target.value)}
    variant="standard"
  />
</Box>
```

You can take a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-panini-c9qy90?file=/src/App.js) for a live working example of this solution.